# Cloudformation is saying SourceSecurityGroupId must be of type String but my !GetAtt ALBSecurityGroup.GroupId I thought would be a string?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-security-group

I'm creating a stack that references a security group in the source of a different security group's ingress rules however the stack fails saying that "SourceSecurityGroupId must be of type string.
I thought that using !GetAtt xyz.GroupId returns a string but that doesn't seem to be happening. Would appreciate thoughts.
This is my code:

```
 AutoscalingSecurityGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Security group for autoscaling
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          SourceSecurityGroupId:
            - !GetAtt ALBSecurityGroup.GroupId
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 443
          ToPort: 443
          SourceSecurityGroupId:
            - !GetAtt ALBSecurityGroup.GroupId
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 443
          ToPort: 443
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0


  ALBSecurityGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Security group for Application Load Balancer
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 443
          ToPort: 443
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: -1
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Not sure what to try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change it to `!Ref ALBSecurityGroup` which will give you the String value.

```
SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref ALBSecurityGroup
```

Comment: That's perfect thank you. Are you able to explain what was going wrong?

Comment: When we pass the logical ID (`ALBSecurityGroup` in your case) of the resource `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup' to the intrinsic Ref function, Ref returns the resource ID (String value) whereas Fn::GetAtt intrinsic function returns a value for a specified attribute. We need to pass an attribute name along with the logical resource ID. See this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html#aws-properties-ec2-security-group-return-values)